# C "for" loop changes pointer value inside a function

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

A link to the project in [Github](https://github.com/OzoneBG/PIK2-Coursework-1/tree/master/Kursova_Variant_N)

So I have a problem with case 5 inside the main function. Where load_array() is called. The actual function resides in functions.c on line 120

The problem is that the for loop changes the value of int* size from 5 to 23

Comment: You've showed how you call `load_array` which is a good idea, but it's not enough, please show how `file_name`,`elements` and `arr` are declared. What is `init`?

Comment: There isn't enough information. In addition to the environment where `load_array` is called, what does `init` do? Don't you mean `int **p`, so that `init` can allocate to `*p`?

Comment: So what does `p` point to? It looks like a classic buffer overflow, with `p` probably pointing to an automatic variable allocated on the stack that isn't an array of at least `sz` ints.

Comment: You should have been getting errors, or at least warnings, when compiling that code. You pass a pointer to a pointer to an `int` (i.e. `int **`) as the alst argument, but the function only takes a pointer to an `int` (`int *`).

Comment: @Kyojin **edit your question, please**.

Comment: Please edit that into your question. `&arr` isn't an `int *`, it is an `int **`. Activate warnings to catch such mismatches.

Comment: Debugger........................

Comment: Style related: `int* size` isn't exactly clever. Just pass it by value, ideally as `size_t size`. Then return 0 if you didn't find the file. (and don't print stuff ...)

Comment: Okay I edited my questions.

@MartinJames I used debugger and array is initialized properly, and its filled properly, but it changes the int* size from 5 to 23

Comment: So, in `void load_array(char* fn, int* size, int* p)`, `p` is an `int*`, you then call `init(p, sz);`, which has the prototype `void init(int** p, int size)`. Are you telling us your compiler has *nothing* to say about that?

Comment: It compiles without any problem. I use Visual Studio 2015. I also declared #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: what is `_MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` ?

Comment: If your compiler doesn't warn about passing an `int*` in place of an `int**`, the compiler sucks.

Comment: #define _MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 100

Comment: @Kyojin update your question

Comment: What is `arr` ? Please read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There have been too many comment only for extracting missing information from you.

Comment: No links please, everything should be containd in the question. Did you read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question should not have ever been answered as it still lacks MCVE **within the question itself**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler should have shouted at you, because the last argument you pass to `load_array` doesn't match the functions formal argument, and it in turn doesn't match what `init` expects.

And if if `p` in the `load_array` function is indeed a pointer to a pointer (i.e. the argument is `int **p`) then the `scanf` call is wrong as the expression `(p + i)` is *also* a pointer to a pointer. And this is most likely the cause of your problem, as it leads to *undefined behavior* and will write the input to somewhere else than you expect.

To fix this you first need to fix the argument type, then use the dereference operator when using `p`, as in `*p + i`.

In short, to be correct the code should look like

```
//                Note extra asterisk here
//                                       |
//                                       v
void load_array(char* fn, int* size, int** p)
{
    ...
    // Note extra asterisk here
    //               |
    //               v
    fscanf(fp, "%d", *p + i);
    // Or fscanf(fp, "%d", &(*p)[i]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now we have enough code to go on. Firstly, `load_array` is intended to allocate and fill an array, passing its location and size back via two pointers, one serving as inout (size) and the other output only (p). `init` is meant to do the allocation, and there's a call side which holds the variables, an `int elements` and (presumably) `int *arr=NULL`.

The problem is, these aren't passed as the same type along the way. The call to `load_array` takes the address of `arr`, therefore an `int**`, but the declaration says it's only an `int*`. It's passed to `init` which expects an `int**`, and it likely works there as it actually was one (but it's still an invalid way to convert pointer types), but when `load_array` starts filling things in it is writing to `p+i`.

`p` at that point points to `arr`, which isn't an int, so even when `i` is low this is the wrong place to put the data. This causes firstly the loss of the buffer `arr` pointed to, secondly invalid data in `arr` such that accessing it later will cause undefined behaviour, and thirdly (once `i` becomes larger than `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`) overwriting of unrelated memory, such as the contents of `elements` which is likely a neighbouring variable.

A likely memory layout could be that `elements` sits on the stack, let's say FP+12..15, then there are four unused bytes to keep `arr` aligned at FP+8..11, and `arr` sits in FP+0..7. This would explain why step `i=3` in particular causes `elements` (alias `*size`) to change.

What you should do is fix the type of `p` and use `*p` in `load_array`, much like it is used in `init`.